# Why lasers are used in inertial nuclear fusion?

Tags: fusion, nuclear-engineering

Why in inertial fusion are used laser rays but not, for example, merely focused light? Is there a problem with precision of focusing or power density?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with focusing of random emitters vs lasers.

Answer (score 1):

When the ICF concept was first developed in 1959, lasers didn’t exist and there were a number of ideas in how to deliver the energy, including particle accelerators, pellet guns and others. When the laser appeared the next year it seemed perfect, not because it is focused, but because it is fast.

One of the key developments as the underlying theory developed was that you can’t just press real hard and hope for the best, the energy needed to get where you have to be is way too high. Instead, what you want to do is get the compression up and then hit that compressed object with a really short burst of extra power. That will cause a shock wave to form that will travel into the fuel, and when it reaches the middle it will suddenly heat that little spot into fusion levels. Those fusions will release alphas which will heat the fuel around it, they’ll give off more alphas, and so on. This is called ignition.

There is a major problem with lasers for this purpose: they are horrible inefficient. In NIF for instance, they put 400 MJ of power into the laser to get 2 MJ of laser at the other end. For this reason there’s been lots of exploration of alternatives, especially new forms of accelerators, but as we did more experiments the timing kept getting tighter and tighter and every time someone came up with a new accelerator an experiment came out that demanded even tighter timing.

So we use lasers simply because they can deliver the exact “shape” of the pulse of energy they need, and nothing else out there, so far, does that for an amount of money we can afford.